# 'id' is a bad variable name in Python

Tags: python

Why is it bad to name a variable `id` in Python?

Comment: Most people append an underscore to identifiers that clash with builtins/keywords: id_, map_, list_, filter_, etc.

Comment: A more sneaky solution would be to use a variable `ID`.

Comment: A better question would be... What genius thought using such a common, generic name for a built-in function was a good idea?

Comment: @Basic it's a standard thing that someone would expect the function to be named, according to what it does. The longer `identity` would be ambiguous (since it could also mean a function that accepts one parameter and returns the same value).

Answer (score 193, accepted):

`id()` is a fundamental built-in:

> Help on built-in function `id` in module
>   `__builtin__`:
>
> ```
> id(...)
>
>     id(object) -> integer
>
>     Return the identity of an object.  This is guaranteed to be unique among
>     simultaneously existing objects.  (Hint: it's the object's memory
>     address.)
> ```

In general, using variable names that eclipse a keyword or built-in function in any language is a bad idea, even if it is allowed.

Comment: OK, for 'id' you're right, but the "in general..." comment still applies, don't you think?

Comment: I would avoid it for module globals certainly. For variables restricted to local scope, so you can see the same function isn't ever going to need to use the builtin, it's not something I'd worry about.

Comment: @Caramdir: Good catch, `id` was slated for removal at one time, but eventually they decided not to remove it.  I'm no longer able to edit my original comment, so I'll delete it to avoid confusing people in the future.

Comment: @EliCourtwright I wish they had removed it. What a poorly named method! A generic, common name used in thousands of places (where context gives meaning). So someone decided to use it as a global name where there is no context?

Comment: Amazingly, Google's own Python regex tutorial (https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions) uses `str = 'an example word:cat!!'`.  Is there anything in any of the PEPs that says don't do this?

Comment: @wordsforthewise also numpy's `np.array` names the first argument `object`, shadowing the built-in type. I have seen many examples of this, including, if I'm not mistaken, in standard modules.

Comment: @MattS yikes!  .

Comment: @MattS It's fine as a parameter name though, cause the shadow is inside the function scope, so you don't need to worry about it. The only chance of confusion I can think of is if you use the parameter name outside of the call, like `object = []; np.array(object)`.

Comment: *"In general, using variable names that eclipse a keyword or built-in function in any language is a bad idea, even if it is allowed."* It's more than just a bad idea in python. Most programming languages use scoped variable names; but python uses dynamic variable names. This means that if you shadow a name, you're breaking all code and functions that refer to that name.

Answer (score 118):

In **PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code**, the following guidance appears in the section [Descriptive: Naming Styles](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) :

> - `single_trailing_underscore_` : used by convention to avoid conflicts
>     with Python keyword, e.g.
>
>   `Tkinter.Toplevel(master, class_='ClassName')`

So, to answer the question, an example that applies this guideline is:

```
id_ = 42
```

Including the trailing underscore in the variable name makes the intent clear (to those familiar with the guidance in PEP 8).

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question, but +1 for the PEP-8 naming convention

Comment: Good advice, but `id` is a builtin, not a keyword, and this doesn't explain why it's bad to shadow a builtin.

Comment: @wjandrea It's bad to shadow a builtin because it makes the code less readable and harder to maintain. You can freely assign `print = 123` but then you or your coworkers will be surprised later in the code why `print('Hello World')` raises a TypeError. PEP8 gives the recommended way how to name such variable.

Comment: @Jeyekomon Where's that in PEP8?

Comment: @wjandrea PEP8 does not explicitly state how to name your variable in case of conflict with builtin. It is up to you to find some solution that fits you well. You can name your variable with three trailing underscores. But every sane person would use the same naming convention as used in the conflicts with keywords since there is no good reason to alter the naming convention based on what you shadow. I wonder what is so difficult to understand about it.

Answer (score 63):

I might say something unpopular here: `id()` is a rather specialized built-in function that is rarely used in business logic. Therefore I don't see a problem in using it as a variable name in a tight and well-written function, where it's clear that id doesn't mean the built-in function.

Comment: In response to: > id is a rather specialized built-in
> function that is rarely used in
> business logic. Therefore I don't see
> a problem in using it as a variable
> name in a tight and well-written
> function, whre it's clear that id
> doesn't mean the built-in function. While this is true, it's probably a good idea to be more specific with this variable name than simply "id". Lots of things have IDs (especially if you're working with a RDBMS), and as the second line of Tim Peters's *The Zen of Python* tells us: > Explicit is better than implicit. See the rest by running: `import this`

Comment: I would still avoid it if at all possible though.  Even if for no other reason than to not hear coworkers complain.  :-)

Comment: I completely agree: naming a variable "id" in a small function (and thus scope) is harmless. Very few people use the `id` builtin anyway. That said it took me a while when a colleague overrode the `list` builtin with a local variable. So the general rule other people mention still makes sense.

Comment: IMHO one could do without `id` nearly everywhere (the only time I can imagine using it outside of [abusive cases](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28851/176) is indirectly when using the `x is y` identity operator, where Python basically does `id(x) == id(y)` for you (i.e. you don't need to call it...). I'd categorically ignore `id` as a builtin, and when you *do* need it in a module, make it super explicit and `import builtins` and call it as `builtins.id`.

Comment: @NickT `x is y` does not call `id()` at all. Try overwriting `id` and then calling the `is` operator.

Comment: @GabrielG. correct, [`is` calls the C `Py_Is`, which compares the pointer addresses of two `PyObject`s](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b4d4aa9e8d61476267951c72321fadffc2d82227/Objects/object.c#L2923-L2926) (or [in this macro](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b4d4aa9e8d61476267951c72321fadffc2d82227/Include/object.h#L239)), while `id()` calls [`builtin_id` which converts the pointer address of one `PyObject` into a `PyLong`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b4d4aa9e8d61476267951c72321fadffc2d82227/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1262). I said 'basically' as a crappy hand-wave.

Answer (score 61):

[`id`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id) is a built-in function that gives the identity of an object (which is also its memory address in CPython). If you name one of your functions `id`, you will have to say [`builtins.id`](https://docs.python.org/library/builtins.html) to get the original (or `__builtins__.id` in CPython). Renaming `id` globally is confusing in anything but a small script.

However, reusing built-in names as variables isn't all that bad as long as the use is local. Python has a *lot* of built-in functions that (1) have common names and (2) you will not use much anyway. Using these as local variables or as members of an object is OK because it's obvious from context what you're doing:

Example:

```
def numbered(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        for i, input in enumerate(file):
            print("%s:\t%s" % (i, input), end='')
```

Some built-ins with tempting names:

- `id`
- `list`, `dict`
- `map`
- `all`, `any`
- `complex`, `int`
- `dir`
- `input`
- `slice`
- `sum`
- `min`, `max`
- `object`
- `file` ([removed in Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins))
- `buffer` ([removed in Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#changes-already-present-in-python-2-6))

Comment: [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which was updated  01-Aug-2013, now advises avoiding potential confusion by simply appending `_` to the variable name. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28091085/1497596).

Comment: It's worth noting that the `id` function returning the memory address of an object is a CPython implementation detail. It's also worth noting that the the function is only required to return a different number for any two _extant_ objects. If an object is garbage collected, its id may be recycled.

Comment: @Zac Thanks! I edited the answer to add that point about the memory address, and a link so people can read more.

Comment: Just a note: in Python 3, `file` is no longer a builtin (though most syntax highlighters still treat it as such).

Answer (score 10):

Others have mentioned that it's confusing, but I want to expand on **why**. Here's an example, based on a true story. Basically, I wrote a class that takes an `id` parameter but then tried to use the builtin `id` later.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, id):
        """Create employee, with their name and badge id."""
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        # ... lots more code, making you forget about the parameter names
        print('Created', type(self).__name__, repr(name), 'at', hex(id(self)))

tay = Employee('Taylor Swift', 1985)
```

Expected output:

```
Created Employee 'Taylor Swift' at 0x7efde30ae910
```

Actual output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "company.py", line 9, in <module>
    tay = Employee('Taylor Swift', 1985)
  File "company.py", line 7, in __init__
    print('Created', type(self).__name__, repr(name), 'at', hex(id(self)))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

> *Huh? Where am I trying to call an int? Those are all builtins...*

If I had named it `badge_id` or `id_`, I wouldn't have had this problem.

**Update**: Thankfully, this part of the error is clearer in Python 3.11+:

```
    print('Created', type(self).__name__, repr(name), 'at', hex(id(self)))
                                                                ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 5):

It's bad to name any variable after a built in function. One of the reasons is because it can be confusing to a reader that doesn't know the name is overridden.

Answer (score 2):

`id` is a built-in function in Python. Assigning a value to `id` will override the function. It is best to either add a prefix as in `some_id` or use it in a different capitalization as in `ID`.

The built in function takes a single argument and returns an integer for the memory address of the object that you passed (in CPython).

```
>>> id(1)
9787760
>>> x = 1
>>> id(x)
9787760
```

Comment: note that you can name a class attribute or method 'id', that won't touch the built in function.

Answer (score -2):

Because it's the name of a builtin function.

Answer (score -6):

Because python is a dynamic language, it's not usually a good idea to give a variable and a function the same name.  id() is a function in python, so it's recommend not to use a variable named id.  Bearing that in mind, that applies to all functions that you might use... a variable shouldn't have the same name as a function.

Comment: "Because python is a dynamic language, it's not usually a good idea to give a variable and a function the same name." -- You cannot give a variable and a function the same name. Nothing to do with it being a dynamic language. If you mean giving *properties* the same names as other objects in the same scope, I also disagree. You may have a class called "Key", an instance of that class called "key" and a property of another object called "key", e.g., "door.key".