# Is it bad practice to use a built-in function name as an attribute or method identifier?

Tags: python, namespaces, python-3.x, reserved-words, naming-conventions

I know to never use built-in function names as variable identifiers.

But are there any reasons not to use them as attribute or method identifiers?

For example, is it safe to write `my_object.id = 5`, or define an instance method `dict` in my own class?

Comment: Related: ['id' is a bad variable name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/77552/95735)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It won't confuse the interpreter but it may confuse people reading your code.  Unnecessary use of builtin names for attributes and methods should be avoided.

Another ill-effect is that shadowing builtins confuses syntax highlighters in most python-aware editors (vi, emacs, pydev, idle, etc.)  Also, some of the lint tools will warn about this practice.

Answer (score 21):

Yes it's bad practice. It might not immediately break anything for you, but it still hurts readability of the code.

To selectively quote from PEP20:

> Beautiful is better than ugly.
>   Simple is better than complex.
>   Readability counts.
>   If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.

Seeing a call to `myobject.dict()` it would be natural to assume that it's going to return `myobject.__dict__`, or that `myobject.id()` returns the same thing as `id(myobject)`

It's possible for them to find out that they're wrong; but that will take time and effort and probably lead to some mistakes while they figure it out. Calling your attribute `myobject.object_id_number` is much longer, but makes it clearer that it's different to `id(myobject)`

Answer (score 12):

No, that's fine. Since an object reference is required there is no way to have them shadow the built-in.

Comment: So I can use any valid identifier as an attribute name, except one starting with `__`, or one that's identical to a keyword?

Comment: you can use any including __something or a keyword. Well, some with __ have special meaning.

Comment: You can start them with `__` so long as they also *end* with `__`. Do note that Python uses many of those for its own purposes though (such as `__dict__`, `__init__`, and `__new__`).

Comment: Is the rule that if they also end with __ they are not mangled?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: oh that's precisely why I thought I shouldn't use them (who knows which are used for the language's "own purposes"). And why if I did risk using them, must I end them with `__`?

Comment: @max: [Python Language Reference, section 3, "Data model"](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html)

Comment: You shouldn't start them with `__` at all. `__foo` get's mangled, which isn't a problem if it's a private property. `__foo__` signifies that it's Python internals. There is no *problem* with doing so, but it is bad form.

Comment: depends on what you mean by "fine". Will the code still run? Sure. Is using built-in names a bad practice and can lead to confusion? Yes, and that should be enough of a reason for anyone to avoid using built-in types/functions as variable names.

Comment: @icdevppl: Even as an attribute name, as the question asks?

Answer (score 0):

I go back and forth on functions a lot when the input variables mimic python builtins.  For example, the word `bytes` is a python builtin, but consider a utility library that parses bytes:

```
def parse_bytes(bytes):
    pass
```

I'd argue this has great *readability*, but pep8 linters don't like it.  Instead I could do

```
def parse_bytes(bytearray):
    pass

def parse_bytes(somebytes):
    pass
```

Or use type hinting

```
def parse_bytes(b: bytes):
    pass
```

But all of these seem worse.  Same thing happens if your variable name is `input`...

At the end of the day I usually go with `somebytes`

Comment: Why not bytes_?