# How to create a file and append data from html page ?

Tags: javascript, python, html, file, server-side

I have an html file on my desktop that takes some input. How would I go about writing that input into a file onto my computer? Would I have to use another language to do it (i.e python or javascript?) and how would I go about doing this? On a related note, is there any way I can have javascript start an application from within an html file (the goal is to write to a file on my computer?

Comment: it needs to send the form somewhere ... (I think html will only support GET (I may be wrong) on the other page you can receive the data and write it... this link may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Browsers have lots of security that prevent this level of control over your computer.  This is a good thing. You dont want random websites to be able to do this stuff on anyone's computer that visits them.

They way to do this would be to write a web application that your browser could access. The browser can submit data to this application running on your own computer and your application could manipulate the file system or do lots of other things.

So no, a browser can't do these things. And yes, you would have to use "another language" to create something which runs outside the browser itself. You can use javascript (see node.js) or python to do this, as well nearly any other programming language that exists to create such a thing. Which to choose is up to you.

Comment: There may be a way with html5, honestly not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use another language. You should see [Save file Javascript with file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717851/save-file-javascript-with-file-name) (this requires you creating it on your website and having the user download it) and [Python Save to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536714/python-save-to-file) (for implementing Python in HTML see [here](http://python.about.com/od/cgiformswithpython/ss/pycgitut2_all.htm)). Or in Javascript you could use  [`ActiveX`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) to save a file by doing*:

ActiveX

```
function WriteToFile()
{
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\Test.txt", true);
s.WriteLine('Hello');
s.Close();
}
```

Python

```
myFile = open('Failed.py', 'w')
myFile.write('whatever')
myFile.close()
```

Javascript (non ActiveX)

```
uriContent = "data:application/octet-stream;filename=filename.txt," + 
          encodeURIComponent(codeMirror.getValue());
newWindow=window.open(uriContent, 'filename.txt');
```

**Note: I really do not recommend using `ActiveX`, see [ActiveX and Javascript do not mix](http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/activex.htm) for more details*

Comment: how would I invoke the python script? with javascript I just put the code between two "<script>" tags.

Comment: @user1678838 I would see http://python.about.com/od/cgiformswithpython/ss/pycgitut2_all.htm

Comment: In python: use closure: `with open('Failed.py','w') as myFile: myFile.write('whatever')`

Comment: @Yevgen Thanks for the tip :), I don't actually do python, but since this question required more javascript/html knowledge, I thought I'd answer it anyways

Answer (score 2):

Right now writing to a local file with Javascript can be done using the `FileWriter` API that is currently only supported by Chrome and Opera:

http://caniuse.com/#search=filewriter

Here is some sample code from HTML5Rocks.com:

```
function onInitFs(fs) {

  fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {

    // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
    fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

      fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
        console.log('Write completed.');
      };

      fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
      };

      // Create a new Blob and write it to log.txt.
      var blob = new Blob(['Lorem Ipsum'], {type: 'text/plain'});

      fileWriter.write(blob);

    }, errorHandler);

  }, errorHandler);

}

window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);
```

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to answer.  If by "it takes some input" you mean there's a `form` element involved then you can process that via a language like [PHP](http://php.net/).

If you're just looking to edit the code and get started with learning HTML, then Notepad/TextEdit and a **modern** web browser are your new best friends.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

you can't. The web browser security and sandbox'ing prevents this.

**Longer answer:**

setup a small LAMP stack, Ruby on rails(local host server), Python/Django(local host server) to host your HTML/web form. The local daemon can handle appending data to a file, as you enter it into a form.

With HTML5, you get special hooks that may allow you to write to the local filesystem, but those may be browser specific and may break from time to time.