# Saving real time data using browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, webserver

I have a webpage that polls the server for updated data and then shows it.  Is there a way that in the browser to have an option of saving that data to file?  For example, if I read the temperature outside and update the webpage with time and temperature I would then like to be able to click a button and save the time and temperature to a text file until the user clicks a stop button.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server - Possibly what you are looking for?

Comment: That appears to let you save a file, I am looking for a way to append new data to a file. Basically open file, append new line of data, then close file.

Comment: This might be relevant, but I've had no time to take a deeper look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468335/how-to-create-a-file-and-append-data-from-html-page

Comment: I still have not found a way to do this, most references are to old articles where I think the browsers now prevent access to file APIs.