# How do I write my generated information from python into a file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was wondering whether I could write the information of the attributes of each character into a text file and how would I be able to do this? The attributes on the notepad file need to be updated every time someone plays the game.

```
def strength():
    dice12 = random.randint(1,12)
    dice04 = random.randint(1,4)
    strfinalstats = dice12/dice04+10
    print ">",strfinalstats,"strength"

def skill():
    dice12 = random.randint(1,12)
    dice04 = random.randint(1,4)
    skfinalstats = dice12/dice04+10
    print ">",skfinalstats,"skill!"

def player1():
    name1=raw_input("what would you like to call the first player?")
    print name1,"has:"
    time.sleep(1)
    strength()
    time.sleep(1)
    skill()

def player2():
    name2=raw_input("what would you like to call the first player?")
    print name2,"has:"
    time.sleep(1)
    strength()
    time.sleep(1)
    skill()

def player3():
    name3=raw_input("what would you like to call the first player?")
    print name3,"has:"
    time.sleep(1)
    strength()
    time.sleep(1)
    skill()
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: There are numerous "How do I write X to a file?" questions on SO Python. Please search for one of those and follow along with a suitable answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Save to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536714/python-save-to-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need:``

```
f = open('filename', 'r+')
```

You can put right below each attribute:

```
f.write(attributes)
```

The attributes on the notepad file will update every time someone plays the game.

P/s: Why you do not declear a class name "player" then create three instance?