# Saving my output code to a separate file?

Tags: python, list

- identify the individual words in a sentence and store them in a list
- create a list of positions for words in that list
- save these lists as a single file or as separate files.

How would i save my output to a separate file?

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDKC1.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536714/python-save-to-file

Comment: Just a note, very obvious comments like "this sets <variable>" are unnecessary and distract from the important comments. Where the code can speak for itself, it's best to let it do so.

Comment: Please [edit] your code into the body of your question. It takes jut a cople seconds to ctrl-C ctrl-V it in, and saves anyone helping you the time of re-writing it themselves. You'll get much better answers if it's easier for the people helping you.

Answer (score 0):

```
file=open("filename.txt","w")
file.write(*map(position.__getitem__, words)) #Your last line 
file.close()
```

By the way, don't share your code through an image and use markdown code formatting like above.

Answer (score 0):

I recognise the question you are trying to answer from GSCE Computing (UK).

Aside from your request as to how to store the words in a file, you use a confusing way to save the position of the words.

Using `position[word] = len(position) + 1` is saving the position of the word in the *list* of words, not the position in the *original sentence*. In fact, the number stored against the `word` in `position` is not used, since you map the *word* against the `words` list to get the position.

Writing to a file is not difficult, do a [search of Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/899176/243925).

Comment: I'm a developer, a friend of mine teaches computer science and he asked me about this question. It's really not too hard if you search  (google) for information about writing a reading to files. As a bit of a hint, you could also think about storing the positions of the words in a string, rather than a list, and write that "word" to a file. Of course, that only works while the position values are less than 10.