# How do I save a text file in python, to my File Explorer?

Tags: python

I've been using Python for a few months, but I'm sort of new to Files. I would like to know how to save text files into my Documents, using ".txt".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Save to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536714/python-save-to-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can create files using the `open()` function, which takes two arguments, the path to the file and the mode. Since you want to make a new file, you should be using the `w+` mode.

```
with open("path_to_my_documents\\filename.txt", 'w+') as f:
    f.write("a string you want to save")
```

Comment: [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm) is a pretty intuitive guide to basic input/output in Python.

Comment: @kindall I was under the impression that 'w' didn't create a new file but I guess I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like to overwrite existing file then use **a** or **a+** mode. This just appends to existing file. **a+** is able to read the file as well