# Python , Get the username in windows and then save it in a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I know that using  `getpass.getuser()` command, I can get the username, but how can I save it in a text file ? So I want python to find the username and then save it in the following file username.txt

Script:

```
os.path.join('..','Documents and Settings','USERNAME','Desktop'))
```

(Python Version 2.7 being used)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Save to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536714/python-save-to-file)

Comment: Add it in a variable and then make python put the variable in a txt document?

Comment: So far your script constructs the string `'../Documents and Settings/USERNAME/Desktop'` and does not even store it. There is no attempt to open or even write a file.

Comment: Btw, Why python 2.7 and not 3? Just curious...

Comment: I'm pretty sure a simple: `os.system('whoami > user.txt')` will store the username in a file.

Comment: python 2.7 because I'm using py2.7 at my school

Answer (score 2):

You have to open a txt file, construct your string then write to it.

```
import getpass

# get your username
username = getpass.getuser()

# open a txt file in append mode
log = open('username.txt', 'a')

# create your string
string = os.path.join('..','Documents and Settings',username,'Desktop')

# save and close the file
log.write(string)
log.close()
```

or you could use pythons 'with' statement which makes sure the file is closed properly.

```
import getpass

# get your username
username = getpass.getuser()

# create your string
string = os.path.join('..','Documents and Settings',username,'Desktop')

with open('username.txt') as file:
    file.write(string)
```