# Python: Why isn't this regular expression being substituted?

Tags: python, regex, string, list, substitution

I was trying to remove middle initials from a list of names so that they all conformed to FirstName space LastName. so I tried writing a regular expression that I could then use to match list items that had a middle initial then replace it with '' an empty space.

Here is my code:

```
import re

list = ['John A Appleseed', 'Bonnie N Clyde', 'Joseph B Barthalomew', 'John Smith']

mid_name = re.compile(r'\s+[A-Z]\s+')

for idx, names in enumerate(list):
    if re.match(mid_name, names) is not None:
        list[idx] = mid_name.sub('', names)

print(list)
```

My results were:

```
['John A Appleseed', 'Bonnie N Clyde', 'Joseph B Barthalomew', 'John Smith']
```

I then changed my regular expression to:

```
mid_name = re.compile(r'\w+\s+[A-Z]\s+\w+')
```

And get:

```
['', '', '', 'John Smith']
```

Then changed the regular expression to:

```
mid_name = re.compile(r'[A-Z]\s+')
```

because I realized I wanted to keep at least one of those spaces anyway, but still got:

```
['John A Appleseed', 'Bonnie N Clyde', 'Joseph B Barthalomew', 'John Smith']
```

What is it that I'm missing? I feel like I'm really close to my solution, but it's alluding me. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: http://regexr.com/  is a great place to experiment regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `re.match` when you should be using `re.search`.

[According to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match), `match` only matches at the beginning of the string whereas `search` matches anywhere in the string.

Another thing to note: you don't need to use `re.match` or `re.search` when you have a compiled regular expression (made with `re.compile`).  You [can do this instead](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile):

```
mid_name = re.compile(r'\s+[A-Z]\s+')
mid_name.search(name)
```

You also probably don't need to check for a match before performing a substitution.  That extra step is unnecessary because a substitution that doesn't actually substitute will give you the original string.  So **compile** and then **sub** only (don't search).

---

Unrelated to your issue: you might want to consider changing your variable names some.

The `list` name is already used to represent the `list` data type so you're [shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109333/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-a-built-in-function-name-as-an-attribute-or-method-ide) that name.  You might consider renaming `list` to `names` and renaming `names` to `name` (since that variable represents just a single name).

Comment: Awesome! I knew I was missing something conceptually. Thank you very much!