# Factory Boy random choice for a field with field option "choices"

Tags: python, django, factory, django-testing, factory-boy

When a field in a Django model has the option choices, see [Django choices field option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#choices), it utilises an iterable containing iterables of 2 items to define which values are allowed. For example:

*Models*

```
class IceCreamProduct(models.Model):
    PRODUCT_TYPES = (
        (0, 'Soft Ice Cream'),
        (1, 'Hard Ice Cream'),
        (2, 'Light Ice Cream'),
        (3, 'French Ice Cream'),
        (4, 'Italian-style Gelato'),
        (5, 'Frozen Dairy Dessert'),
    )
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Type', choices=PRODUCT_TYPES, default=0)
```

To generate a random value in Factory Boy for choices I would utilise factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice, but this only chooses an iterable of 2 items. It can not take the first item of the chosen iterable. For example:

*Factories*

```
class IceCreamProductFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = IceCreamProduct

    type = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(IceCreamProduct.PRODUCT_TYPES)
```

*Error*

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'
```

Getting the first item of the tuple is not possible. For example:

*Factories*

```
class IceCreamProductFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = IceCreamProduct

    type = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(IceCreamProduct.PRODUCT_TYPES)[0]
```

*Error*

```
TypeError: 'FuzzyChoice' object does not support indexing
```

It is possible with the default Python random iterator, but this generates a value on declaration time and so every factory object will have the same random value. For example:

*Factories*

```
class IceCreamProductFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = IceCreamProduct

    type = random.choice(IceCreamProduct.PRODUCT_TYPES)][0]
```

How can this be solved in Factory Boy? Do I need to create a custom FuzzyAttribute? (If so, please give an example)

Comment: Hi, Robin and All

just got a new similar question, how factory boy behave, if the the choice attribute is not covered in the factory. will it automatically select one in the choices?
I did not get this answer in factory boy's document. Thanks

Comment: @tim If you do not define the field (which has the choices attribute) in the factory, then it will take the value of the "default" attribute of that field. Are you getting an error or something? Because you should just be able to try it.

Comment: my case is that there is a test case I wrote, occasionally failed in pipeline, but always passing when running locally, I want to know the reason, I find one potential issue might be choice selecting...

Comment: @tim I think I might have had similar "random failure" problems before with factories. You might want to check how you create the factory: you can use "ice_cream = IceCreamProductFactory()    ice_cream.save()" or you can use "ice_cream = IceCreamProductFactory.create()", the last of which seems to have been working more reliably in my case.
Also, did you try adding the choice attribute and seeing if it was more stable?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You'll not need a FuzzyAttribute.

You can either restrict the values possible and only give the int value of each product type to FuzzyChoice by doing something like this:

```py
from factory import fuzzy

PRODUCT_IDS = [x[0] for x in IceCreamProduct.PRODUCT_TYPES]
class IceCreamProductFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = IceCreamProduct

    type = fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(PRODUCT_IDS)
```

It should do the work.

Please be aware that fuzzy module has been deprecated recently, see [*Fuzzy Attributes Documentation*](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fuzzy.html), you may want to use a LazyFunction instead.

Comment: Thank you! This solves my problem. I'll also take try to replace all my fuzzy attributes,

Comment: At the current time the fuzzy module doesn't even exist anymore in the factory_boy package

Comment: At the current time, we'll use  `factory.Iterator(CHOICES)`.

Answer (score 12):

You can do as easy as this

```
class IceCreamProductFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    icecream_flavour = factory.Faker(
        'random_element', elements=[x[0] for x in IceCreamProduct.PRODUCT_TYPES]
    )

    class Meta:
        model = IceCreamProduct
```

PS. Don't use `type` as attribute, [it is a bad practice to use a built-in function name as an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9109333/5751147)

Comment: Does not work in my case (yet):
  raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])

Comment: Please view my topic related to this error on [Django Factoryboy fill modelfield with choices throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371682/django-factoryboy-fill-modelfield-with-choices-throws-error).

Comment: @ArtemBernatskyi According PS.
What we should use instead of `type` field ? Any alternatives ?

Comment: @R.García , I've updated the answer, speaking of alternatives to using `type` we can use any synonym which suits our context for example category/flavour/sort.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I was able to do it using `factory.LazyFunction` as lothiraldan suggested:

```
import random

...


def get_license_type():
    "Return a random license type from available choices."
    lt_choices = [x[0] for x in choices.LICENSE_TYPE_CHOICES]
    return random.choice(lt_choices)


def get_line_type():
    "Return a random line type from available choices."
    lt_choices = [x[0] for x in choices.LINE_TYPE_CHOICES]
    return random.choice(lt_choices)


class ProductFactory(ModelFactory):
    name = factory.Faker('name')
    description = factory.Faker('text')
    license_type = factory.LazyFunction(get_license_type)
    line_type = factory.LazyFunction(get_line_type)

    class Meta:
        model = 'products.ProductBaseV2'
```

Answer (score 6):

Because I had to do that for quite a lot of models, I came up with a more abstract version of erichonkanen's solution. I define a helper class, which I put in the top level test directory of my project and import it to the modules containing the factories:

`test/helpers.py`

```
import factory
import random


class ModelFieldLazyChoice(factory.LazyFunction):
    def __init__(self, model_class, field, *args, **kwargs):
        choices = [choice[0] for choice in model_class._meta.get_field(field).choices]
        super(ModelFieldLazyChoice, self).__init__(
            function=lambda: random.choice(choices),
            *args, **kwargs
        )
```

and in `app/factories.py`

```
from app.models import IceCreamProduct
from test.helpers import ModelFieldLazyChoice

class IceCreamProductFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = IceCreamProduct

    type = ModelFieldLazyChoice(IceCreamProduct, 'type')
```

Answer (score 4):

If you make the choices class-based...

```
class IceCreamProduct(models.Model):
    class ProductTypes(models.TextChoices):
        soft_ice_crem = (0, 'Soft Ice Cream')
        hard_ice_cream = (1, 'Hard Ice Cream')
        ...

class IceCreamProductFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = IceCreamProduct

    type = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(IceCreamProduct.ProductTypes)
    ...
```

Comment: here's the documentation reference
https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#fuzzying-django-model-field-choices