# Django FactoryBoy: fill modelfield with choices throws error

Tags: python, django, factory, factory-boy

I am working on a factory for a model and I am trying fill a field that has a list of choices. When I attempt to create an object with the Factory where I attempt to fill in a random choice from the choice list, an exception is thrown:

> TypeError: 'choice' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/factory/base.py", line 551, in build
    return cls._generate(enums.BUILD_STRATEGY, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/factory/base.py", line 505, in _generate
    return step.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/factory/builder.py", line 279, in build
    kwargs=kwargs,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/factory/base.py", line 312, in instantiate
    return self.factory._build(model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/factory/base.py", line 531, in _build
    return model_class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 571, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'choice' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Versions used:

```
django==1.11
factory-boy==2.9.2
python==2.7.12
```

The (cropped) model:

```
class Server(models.Model):

    TEST = 'test'
    ACCEPT = 'accept'

    SERVER_TYPES = (
        (TEST, _("Testing Server")),
        (ACCEPT, _("Acceptation Server"))
    )

    type = models.CharField(_("Server type"), max_length=50, choices=SERVER_TYPES)
```

The (cropped) factory:

```
class ServerFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):

    type = factory.Faker('random_element', elements=[choice[0] for choice in Server.SERVER_TYPES)

    class Meta:
        model = Server
```

In stead of using `Faker('random_element, elements=[..])`, I've also tried using the `LazyFunction`:

```
def get_server_type():
    choices = [choice[0] for choice in Server.SERVER_TYPES]
    return random.choice(choices)

class ServerFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):

    organization = factory.SubFactory(OrganizationFactory)
    type = factory.LazyFunction(get_server_type)

    .. Meta ..
```

This also throws the same error. I also cannot find any real other alternatives to fix this. Any suggestions how I can fill the `type` field with one of the `SERVER_TYPES` choices while using the `factory` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this instead?

```
from random import choice
type = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda x: choice(Server.SERVER_TYPES)[0])
```

Old comment based on initial description of the question:

*it should be `type = factory.Faker('random_element', elements=[choice[0] for choice in Server.SERVER_TYPES])`*

Comment: Thank you for your response, and my apologies for the bad copy-paste. I copy-pasted from a `redo`, but was one `redo` too early. It is `choice[0]`. I updated my question.