# Find the most frequent words that appear in the dataset

Tags: python, list

I write a function that takes as input a list and returns the most common item in the list.

```
##Write the function
def most_frequent(List): 
    dict = {} 
    count, itm = 0, '' 
    for item in reversed(List): 
        dict[item] = dict.get(item, 0) + 1
        if dict[item] >= count : 
            count, itm = dict[item], item 
    return(item) 
  
    return num 

# verfiy the code 

list = [5,42,34,6,7,4,2,5]
print(most_frequent(list))
```

and then download two text file to get the most frequent words.

```
# Download the files restaurants.txt and restaurant-names.txt from Github
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ipeirotis/introduction-to-python/master/data/restaurant-names.txt -o restaurant-names.txt
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ipeirotis/introduction-to-python/master/data/restaurants.txt -o restaurants.txt



# create the list from the restaurants.txt
  List = open("restaurants.txt").readlines()

# get the most most frequent restaurant names
print("The most frequent restaurant names is ",most_frequent(List))

print(most_common(List))
```

but when i try to find the most frequent words that appear in the restaurant names. I got the same result. Could  you help to check whether this is correct or not? Thanks

```
 # create the list from the restaurants.txt
List = open("restaurants.txt").readlines()

# get the most most frequent restaurant names
print("The most frequent restaurant names is ",most_frequent(List))
```

Comment: There is a built-in class which does that for you... `collections.Counter(List).most_common(1)[0][0]`

Comment: When you test your function with known values does it work?

Comment: Related: [Is it bad practice to use a built-in function name as an attribute or method identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109333/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-a-built-in-function-name-as-an-attribute-or-method-ide),

Answer (score 1):

It's `return itm` (most common item) instead of `return item` (last part of your reversed list)

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you might be using the wrong filename for the restauarant names file. Judging from your curl command:

`!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ipeirotis/introduction-to-python/master/data/restaurant-names.txt -o restaurant-names.txt`

The filename you should be using is `restaurant-names.txt` so your code should be:

```py
 # create the list from the restaurants.txt
List = open("restaurants-names.txt").readlines()

# get the most most frequent restaurant names
print("The most frequent restaurant names is ",most_frequent(List))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However this is not the error. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It might be the function that is wrong, what if you try the same test data but in a different order, for example: `list = [42,5,34,6,5,7,4,2]` instead of `list = [5,42,34,6,7,4,2,5]`, is the output still 5?

Comment: You're right. It returns 42. I'm new to python. Could you help to point out the error? Thanks

Comment: You store the most common item in the `itm` variable right? So you can just `return itm` instead of `return item`