# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable python

Tags: python, list, csv, integer

I'm trying to return a range of Pokemon by their number using a CSV file, using a minimum and a maximum, so I want to change the numbers to an integer. So far, I have only been able to return one exact Pokemon if I don't take the inputs as an integer. My CSV is 801 lines long, poke[0] is their number, and poke[1] is their name.

```
def number(list):
  newlist = []
  x = 0
  q2 = int(input("Minimum number? "))
  q3 = int(input("Maximum number? "))
  for poke in range(1,800):
    poke[0] = int(poke[0])
  for poke in list:
    if poke[0] >= q2 and poke[0] <= q3:
      newlist.append(poke[0] + " " + poke[1])
  for poke in newlist:
    print(newlist[x])
    x = x + 1
```

Comment: Where is the code that reads from a csv file?

Comment: FYI you shouldn't literally name something `list` in Python since that's a built-in reserved word. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109333/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-a-built-in-function-name-as-an-attribute-or-method-ide

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop, your are incrementing poke as an integer in range 1, 800. This integer can not be indexed.

Comment: So how would I could I turn it into an integer?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I just changed poke[0] on the first item on the CSV to 0, then changed the loop to accustom the whole list.

Comment: `for poke in list:
    poke[0] = int(poke[0])
  for poke in list:
    if poke[0] >= q2 and poke[0] <= q3:
      a = str(poke[0]) + " " + str(poke[1])
      newlist.append(a)`