# printing string letter according to arbitrary index

Tags: python, list, indexing, data-structures

I have a string str="vivian_wang" and I have a list variable lst = [1,4]. How can I print the letter in the string against my variable lst as index.

Comment: Anything wrong with `print([str[index] for index in lst])`?

Comment: Also, don't use `str` as a variable name, as it [shadows builtins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109333/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-a-built-in-function-name-as-an-attribute-or-method-ide).

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 0):

so I'm guessing in this example, you'd want to print out str[1] and str[4] — based on the values in 'lst'

```
for item in lst:
    print(str[item])
```