# Printing list of user inputted names

Tags: python, list

Hey all was hoping for some help with this piece of code.
The code needs the user to input a name until done is typed and it should provide an output of Hello (name) for every name inputted. Below is the code I have written:

```
names = input("Enter a name:")
list = []

while True:
  
  if names == 'done':
    break
  
  list.append(names)
    
print("Hello",list)
```

After I run the code and enter a name nothing happens, it won't allow me to input another name or even done and I have to shut it down. Any help or tips would greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Where do you ask for names? Right - OUTSIDE the loop. Why think it would ask more then once?

Answer (score 0):

Move `names = input("Enter a name:")` into the `while True:` block.  This will mean that input is requested for every iteration until the input is equal to `'done'`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
list_of_names = []
while True:
  names = input("Enter a name:")  
  if names == 'done':
    break
  print("Hello",names)
  list_of_names.append(names)
```

With this the program keeps running until you input `done` and for every iteration it prints the current value of `names`

Comment: `list` is not a good variable name, as it shadows a builtin.

Comment: The indentation of your code doesn't look quite right either; it prints on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: That is what the OP wants I think: "The code needs the user to input a name until done is typed and it should provide an output of Hello (name) for every name inputted"

Comment: Why would OP's code contain a print outside of the while loop, in that case? Printing out the list at the end would satisfy this criteria.

Comment: I would call that an error in their code... They also included the print statement for the current name outside of the loop.

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. You need to move the `input()` call inside the `while` loop, so that you can accept multiple names.
2. `list` is not a good variable name, [as it shadows the `list()` builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9109333/17769815).

Here is a code snippet that resolves both issues:

```py
name = ""
data = []
while name != 'done':
  name = input("Enter a name:")
  if name != 'done':
    print("Hello", name)
    data.append(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to initialize the global variables that you will need:

`names = ''`

`list1= []` I change the name from `list` to `list1` since its a keyword in python.

Second, take in the input:

`while names != 'done': names = input("Enter a name:") list1.append(names)`

Since done will be added to the list we need to remove it:

`list1.remove('done')`

Code:

```
names = ''
list1= []

while names != 'done':
     names = input("Enter a name:")
     list1.append(names)

list1.remove('done')

for x in names: 
     print('Hello',x)
```