# Pymongo find by _id in subdocuments

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Assuming that this one item of my database:

```
{"_id" : ObjectID("526fdde0ef501a7b0a51270e"),
  "info": "foo",
  "status": true,
  "subitems : [ {"subitem_id" : ObjectID("65sfdde0ef501a7b0a51e270"),
                 //more},
                {....}
              ],
  //more
}
```

I want to find (or find_one, doesn't matter) the document(s) with `"subitems.subitem_id" : xxx`.

I have tried the following. All of them return an empty list.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient,errors
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

id = '65sfdde0ef501a7b0a51e270'

db.col.find({"subitems.subitem_id" : id } ) #obviously wrong
db.col.find({"subitems.subitem_id" : Objectid(id) })
db.col.find({"subitems.subitem_id" : {"$oid":id} })
db.col.find({"subitems.subitem_id.$oid" : id })
db.col.find({"subitems.$.subitem_id" : Objectid(id) })
```

In mongoshell this one works however:

```
find({"subitems.subitem_id" : { "$oid" : "65sfdde0ef501a7b0a51e270" } })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double checked. Right answer is `db.col.find({"subitems.subitem_id" : Objectid(id)})`
Be aware that this query will return full record, not just matching part of sub-array.

Mongo shell:

```
a = ObjectId("5273e7d989800e7f4959526a")
db.m.insert({"subitems": [{"subitem_id":a},
                          {"subitem_id":ObjectId()}]})
db.m.insert({"subitems": [{"subitem_id":ObjectId()},
                          {"subitem_id":ObjectId()}]})
db.m.find({"subitems.subitem_id" : a })

>>> { "_id" : ObjectId("5273e8e189800e7f4959526d"), 
"subitems" : 
[
 {"subitem_id" : ObjectId("5273e7d989800e7f4959526a") },    
 {"subitem_id" : ObjectId("5273e8e189800e7f4959526c")} 
]}
```

Comment: The quality of answers gets improved a lot when given additional explanations.

Comment: Improved and added examples.

Comment: Notice the typographical errors in this answer, and on the question.  Where you see Objectid, or ObjectID, it should read ObjectId. Capital letter I and lowed case letter d. Both in JavaScript and Python.

Comment: There are no errors in answer. It's tested in Mongo shell and copy-pasted here. Fixed typos in question.

Answer (score 5):

The literal `65sfdde0ef501a7b0a51e270` is not hexadecimal, hence, not a valid ObjectId.

Also, `id` is a Python built-in function. Avoid reseting it.

Finally, you execute a find but do not evaluate it, so you do not see any results. Remember that pymongo cursors are lazy.

Try this.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

db = MongoClient().database
oid = '65cfdde0ef501a7b0a51e270'

x = db.col.find({"subitems.subitem_id" : ObjectId(oid)})

print list(x)
```

Notice I adjusted oid to a valid hexadecimal string.

Same query in the Mongo JavaScript shell.

```
db.col.find({"subitems.subitem_id" : new ObjectId("65cfdde0ef501a7b0a51e270")})
```

Comment: There are big difference between id and id(). I don't see any problems specifyin `id = 5`

Comment: If you do `id = 5`, the `id()` built-in is effectively hidden in that scope. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552.