# Python :: passing a list as parameter

Tags: python, list, dictionary

`responses` in `pyen`, a thin library for music data, returns dictionaries in this fashion:

```
{u'id': u'AR6SPRZ1187FB4958B', u'name': u'Wilco'}
```

I'm looping through and printing artists:

```
response = en.get('artist/search', artist_location='Chicago')

artists = response['artists']
for artist in artists:
   sys.stdout.write("song by {}\n".format(artist['name']))
```

but I'd like to pass a list of `ids` here:

```
  response = en.get('song/search', artist_ids = ?) //pass a list here?
  for song in response['songs']:
  sys.stdout.write("\t{}\n".format(song['title']))
```

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [Echo Nest API](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/song.html#search), you'll see that song search by artist_id doesn't support multiple params.

Thus, that's a restriction on pyen, as well, being a consumer of that API.

Instead, you'll have to print songs in a loop of requests:

```
artist_ids = ['AR54RGR1187FB51D10', 'AR6SPRZ1187FB4958B', 'AR5KAA01187FB5AEB7']
for artist_id in artist_ids:
    for song in en.get('song/search', artist_id=artist_id).get('songs', []):
        sys.stdout.write("\t{}\n".format(song['title']))
```

Comment: You should use another variable name instead of `id`, as it shadows the built-in function

Comment: @Francisco strictly speaking yes, but I generally tend to agree with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/77925/771848).

Comment: I tried it, but it raises an exception: `artist_id - Only one value allowed for parameter.`

Comment: @data_garden I'm pretty sure you didn't try it as intended.  artist_ids should be a simple list of ids, e.g. `artist_ids = [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @Steven Moseley you mean: `artist_ids = ['AR54RGR1187FB51D10', 'AR6SPRZ1187FB4958B', 'AR5KAA01187FB5AEB7']`, so you'd have to output a list of `ids` beforehand. please edit this and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

`pyen` is a very thin wrapper, you should always check the EchoNest API docs directly. According to the [API documentation](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/song.html#search), the `song/search` endpoint does not accept multiple `artist_id`s.