# splitting a string with a unicode delimiter?

Tags: python, split

Given the string:

```
str = 'Led Zeppelin — Blackdog'
```

how do I split it at `—`, ending up with:

```
['Led Zeppelin', 'Blackdog']
```

but `—` is not an hyphen; it is encoded as `u'\u2014'`

how do I do it?

Comment: `str.split(u'—')` or `str.split(u'\u2014')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just split on explicitly what you've provided if you want it to be clear that it is *not* a hyphen, surrounded by a whitespace character if that is standard-included with the character. Also, don't [shadow built-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552/id-is-a-bad-variable-name-in-python) with `str` as a variable name.

```
>>> s = 'Led Zeppelin — Blackdog'
>>> s.split(u' \u2014 ')
['Led Zeppelin', 'Blackdog']
>>> s.split(' — ') # perhaps less explicit
['Led Zeppelin', 'Blackdog']
```