# The glob.glob function to extract data from files

Tags: python-2.7, biopython

I am trying to run the script below. The intention of the script is to open different fasta files one after the other, and extract the geneID. The script works well if I don't use the glob.glob function. I get this message **TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found**

```
files='/home/pathtofiles/files'
    #print files
    #sys.exit()
    for file in files:
        fastas=sorted(glob.glob(files + '/*.fasta'))
        #print fastas[0]
        output_handle=(open(fastas, 'r+'))
        genes_files=list(SeqIO.parse(output_handle, 'fasta'))
        geneID=genes_files[0].id
        print geneID
```

I am running of ideas on how to direct the script to open when file after another to give me the require information.

Comment: Is `fastas` a list? i.e. in here `output_handle=(open(fastas, 'r+'))`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*This is way I solved the problem, and this script works.*

```
    import os,sys
    import glob
    from Bio import SeqIO

def extracting_information_gene_id():
    #to extract geneID information and add the reference gene to each different file

    files=sorted(glob.glob('/home/path_to_files/files/*.fasta'))
    #print file
    #sys.exit()
    for file in files:
        #print file
        output_handle=open(file, 'r+')
        ref_genes=list(SeqIO.parse(output_handle, 'fasta'))
        geneID=ref_genes[0].id
        #print geneID
        #sys.exit()

        #to extract the geneID as a reference record from the genes_files
        query_genes=(SeqIO.index('/home/path_to_file/file.fa', 'fasta'))
        #print query_genes[geneID].format('fasta') #check point
        #sys.exit()
        ref_gene=query_genes[geneID].format('fasta')
        #print ref_gene #check point
        #sys.exit()
        output_handle.write(str(ref_gene))
        output_handle.close()
        query_genes.close()

extracting_information_gene_id()
print 'Reference gene sequence have been added'
```

Comment: What is the use of `.format('fasta')` in the line `ref_gene=query_genes[geneID].format('fasta')`?

Comment: Please fix your indentation, because the script as posted will not work.

Comment: @BioGeek. [link](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqIO-pysrc.html). This is a very elegant way to format my extracted sequence as fasta format. Instead of going through the` '>' + gene +'\n' + seq +'\n'`. It is one of Biopython features.

Comment: @BioGeek. Also it prints it in a nice fasta format.

Comment: cool! I didn't knew you could do that. I learned something new today, thanks! :-)

Comment: @BioGeek. We always learn news things, that the good thing about Science. I don't know if you can use it always but put a link in my previous comment that you can have a look, and see it uses.

Answer (score 3):

I see what you are trying to do, but let me first explain why your current approach is not working.

You have a path to a directory with fasta files and you want to loop over the files in that directory. But observe what happens if we do:

```
>>> files='/home/pathtofiles/files'
>>> for file in files:
>>>    print file
/
h
o
m
e
/
p
a
t
h
t
o
f
i
l
e
s
/
f
i
l
e
s
```

Not the list of filenames you expected! `files` is a string and when you apply a `for` loop on a string you simply iterate over the characters in that string.

Also, as [doctorlove](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055118/doctorlove) correctly observed, in your code `fastas` is a list and `open` expects a path to a file as first argument. That's why you get the `TypeError: ... need string, ... list found`.

As an aside (and this is more a problem on Windows then on Linux or Mac), but it is good practice to always use [raw string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals) (prefix the string with an `r`) when working with pathnames to prevent the unwanted expansion of backslash escaped sequences like `\n` and `\t` to newline and tab.

```
>>> path = 'C:\Users\norah\temp'
>>> print path
C:\Users
orah    emp
>>> path = r'C:\Users\norah\temp'
>>> print path
C:\Users\norah\temp
```

Another good practice is to use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) when combining pathnames and filenames. This prevents subtle bugs where your script works on your machine bug gives an error on the machine of your colleague who has a different operating system.

I would also recommend [using the `with` statement when `open`ing files](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python). This assures that the filehandle gets properly closed when you're done with it.

As a final remark, [`file` is a built-in function in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) and it is [bad practice to use a variable with the same name as a built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552/id-is-a-bad-variable-name-in-python) function because that can cause bugs or confusion later on.

Combing all of the above, I would rewrite your code like this:

```
import os
import glob
from Bio import SeqIO

path = r'/home/pathtofiles/files'
pattern = os.path.join(path, '*.fasta')
for fasta_path in sorted(glob.glob(pattern)):
    print fasta_path
    with open(fasta_path, 'r+') as output_handle:
        genes_records = SeqIO.parse(output_handle, 'fasta')
        for gene_record in genes_records:
            print gene_record.id
```