# gmail python client api import message shows Syntax error

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

gmail python api `service.users().messages().import` shows Syntax error here is line of code

```
mgg = services.users().messages().import(userId='me', raw=base64.urlsafe_b64encode(mime_msg.as_string()), labelIds=mime_msg.get('labelIds')).execute()
```

error is showing at bracket of `import(`

If I change `import` to something such as `importee` then it is showing this error
`AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'importee'`
So looks like it is related to?

> Python Reserved Keyword

I have also submitted bug in gmail api here is link to [google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70972649)

Comment: Some of the time, on a syntax error, the problem comes in the lines _before_ where the error message says it is. Show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @DavidG DalmTo. okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552/id-is-a-bad-variable-name-in-python#comment115219_77552) by user [cdleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3594/cdleary) that helped. Work-around is I appended `_` to `import`.
`service.users().messages().import_()` is working. Though still I have issue open in Google issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since import is a reserved word in Python, the Google python library will append a "_" to the API method name.  Use:

```
service.users().messages().import_(....)
```

The documentation is currently (as of late 2017) incorrect and there's an open issue to fix it.  See:  https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/issues/408

Comment: thanks for more info. And but since you were little late then my answer so I should choose my answer???