# Assigning a pair of variables to the min/max of two variables in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, syntactic-sugar

I would like to assign two quantities to the variables `min` and `max`, depending on their value. Suppose `f` is a function which returns an integer value. Is there any way I can do something like

```
min, max = f(1), f(2)
```

which accounts for the values of `f(1)` and `f(2)`? Clearly the above assigns `f(1)` to `min` and `f(2)` to max regardless of their value.

Comment: `... = sorted((f(1), f(2)))` if I'm understanding this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just sort an iterable of the return values before assigning them to `min_v` and `max_v`.

```
min_v, max_v = sorted((f(1), f(2)))
```

If you had a small iterable of return values (but more than 2), using [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) might be alright.

```
min_v, *_, max_v = sorted(map(f, some_small_list))
```

But of course if you applied `f` to a list of any considerable length, it is far more efficient to pluck out the min and max with the built-ins (which you [shouldn't shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552/id-is-a-bad-variable-name-in-python)) rather than sort and unpack.

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like:

```
min, max = (f(1),(f2)) if f(1)<f(2) else (f(2),f(1))
```

If this is what you were looking for.

Comment: this calls the functions twice

Comment: For those interested, this is the type of issue [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) tries to address.

Comment: @chepner how would an assignment expression be used here?

Comment: I assume something like `min, max = a, b if a:=f(1) < b:=f(2) else b, a` (assuming `:=` wins out). Or `min, max = a, b if a < b else b, a given (a, b) = (f(1), f(2))`. (Plus or minus some parentheses)