# Is there a way to remove duplicate list items based on nested lists independent of the order of nested list items?

Tags: python, duplicates, nested-lists

I am trying to remove duplicates from a nested list that contains a nested list combination and float value:

```
list = [
[['Milk', 'Bread', 'Diaper'], 40.0], 
[['Milk', 'Diaper', 'Bread'], 40.0], 
[['Milk', 'Diaper', 'Beer'], 40.0], 
[['Milk', 'Beer', 'Diaper'], 40.0], 
[['Diaper', 'Bread', 'Milk'], 40.0], 
[['Diaper', 'Bread', 'Beer'], 40.0], 
[['Diaper', 'Milk', 'Bread'], 40.0], 
[['Diaper', 'Milk', 'Beer'], 40.0], 
[['Diaper', 'Beer', 'Bread'], 40.0], 
[['Diaper', 'Beer', 'Milk'], 40.0], 
[['Beer', 'Bread', 'Diaper'], 40.0], 
[['Beer', 'Milk', 'Diaper'], 40.0], 
[['Beer', 'Diaper', 'Bread'], 40.0], 
[['Beer', 'Diaper', 'Milk'], 40.0]
]
```

I need to be able to remove items from the outer list based on removing the duplicates of the nested list regardless of the order of items in the nested list.

The output needs to be one instance of every combination:

```
updated_list = [
[['Milk', 'Bread', 'Diaper'], 40.0],
[['Diaper', 'Beer', 'Bread'], 40.0], 
[['Beer', 'Diaper', 'Milk'], 40.0]
]
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's `set` and `frozenset` for this:

```
seen_it = set()
updated_list = []
for line in list:
    key = frozenset(line[0])
    if key not in seen_it:
        seen_it.add(key)
        updated_list.append(line)
```

Notice that `seen_it` keeps track of which sublists we've seen before to avoid adding to the unique lines in `updated_list`.

Also notice that keys in `seen_it` are `frozenset` type, which ignores order like `set`, but is immutable so it can go within another set.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you for the code and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) or, if the sublists can have duplicate elements, a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

A set is an unordered collection of unique elements, so `{1, 2, 3}` is equivalent to `{3, 2, 1}`. If you pass a list to `set`, it will create a set with the list's elements. However, if the same value was in the list twice, that information is lost in the set.

```
# These are both the set {1, 2, 3}
s1 = {3, 1, 2, 1}
s2 = set([2, 1, 3, 3, 2])
assert s1 == s2 # True
```

If you might have duplicates in the lists, the data type you need is a multiset. Unfortunately, Python does not provide a multiset. However, `Counter` works for many of a multiset's use cases, including comparison.

```
from collections import Counter
# These counters have different numbers of each value
c1 = Counter(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'])
c2 = Counter(['c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c'])
assert c1 == c2 # False
```

As for actually removing the duplicates, the [Itertools Recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) `unique_everseen` should serve your needs. If you don't care about duplicates in the other list elements, you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as the `key` function.

---

Also, you shouldn't use "list" as a variable name; [it's bad to shadow the builtins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77612/7389264).