# How can I safely escape a shell command with lots of quotes as a Python string?

Tags: python, regex, string, awk

I have the following awk command:

```
 awk FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" '{ print  $7048 }' ...
```

I want to submit it using `os.system(cmd)`,
but I cannot find the right way to write the code in a python string with all the special characters.
The following is  my latest try:

```
 cmd = " awk -v  FPAT=\"([^,]+)|(\\""[^\\""]+\\"")""  ' {{ print   %s  }} '  %s  > %s" .format(c,input,output)
```

and I get the following result:

```
' awk -v  FPAT="([^,]+)|(\\[^\\]+\\)  \' { print   %s  } \'  %s  > %s'
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I'd use a raw longstring. [Example](https://ideone.com/dbddiv)

Comment: BTW, you can also use raw-escaped triple-quotes. `cmd = r''' ...command here... '''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `input()` to conveniently convert text into a string that you can copy-paste into your source code:

```
>>> cmd = input()
 awk FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" '{ print  $7048 }' ...
>>> cmd
' awk FPAT="([^,]+)|(\\"[^\\"]+\\")" \'{ print  $7048 }\' ...'
```

In Python 2, use `raw_input()` instead.

BTW, avoid using `input` as a variable name since it [shadows the builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77552/4518341) `input()`, and would make this method not work.

---

Or, if the text doesn't contain any triple-quotes, you can use a triple-quoted raw string:

```
>>> cmd = r''' awk FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" '{ print  $7048 }' ...'''
>>> cmd
' awk FPAT="([^,]+)|(\\"[^\\"]+\\")" \'{ print  $7048 }\' ...'
```

*<sub>Credit to [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) for suggesting the raw string option in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63346425/how-can-i-safely-escape-a-shell-command-with-lots-of-quotes-as-a-python-string/63346514#comment112013695_63346425).</sub>*

Comment: Do we really care about Python 2 anymore, unless specifically mentioned by the OP?

Comment: That said, I don't think `input` is necessary for the question; it's about how to format a string suitable for use with `os.system`, not how to input a string from standard input.

Comment: @chepner That's why I didn't mention it in the first place. But since it's such a minor addition, and could be super confusing to a newbie, I added it.

Comment: @chepner Oh yeah you're right, the question's a bit ambiguous. Where OP's double-quotes aren't properly escaped, I assumed that's what they're asking. I edited to clarify what I mean a bit.

Comment: i am confused. when you use re the triple-quoted raw string, why does the d output has 2 backslashes?

Comment: @Emile See [Why do backslashes appear twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24085680/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks! and sorry if it was a dumb question

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the placeholders used by the `%` operator with the field specifiers used by the `format` method.

```
cmd = "awk -v  FPAT=\"([^,]+)|(\\""[^\\""]+\\"")""  ' {{ print   {}  }} '  {}  > {}" .format(c, input, output)
```

Further, you should use the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system`. Python can handle the output redirection, so you don't need a shell.

```
with open(output, "w") as f:
    subprocess.run(["awk", "-v", 'FPAT=([^,]+)|("[^\\"]+")', '{{ print {} }}'.format(c), input])
```

Assuming Python 3.6 or later, you can simplify the `awk` script using an f-string literal.

```
with open(output, "w") as f:
    subprocess.run(["awk", "-v", 'FPAT=([^,]+)|("[^\\"]+")', f'{{ print {c} }}', input])
```