# Why won't my python class inherit from another class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, super, self

```
class Media_Work(object):

  def __init__(self):

    _id: int = 0
    _IdDict: {} 
    _titleDict: {}

class Poem(Media_Work):

  def __init__(self, id, title, author, content, age, mtype, verbs):

    super().__init__()
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.author = author
    self.content = content
    self.age = age
    self.mtype = mtype
    self.verbs = verbs

    Poem._IdDict.update({id: self})
```

My error message:

AttributeError: 'Poem' object has no attribute '_IdDict'

Similar error if I change the bottom line to:

```
self._IdDict.update({id:self})
```

New error message:

AttributeError: type object 'Poem' has no attribute '_IdDict'

Comment: `Media_Work.__init__()` doesn't actually assign anything to `_IdDict` or `_titleDict`: it merely contains malformed type hints for these attributes.

Comment: Presumably in the parent class `__init__()` you intended to assign `self._IdDict = {}`.  But you didn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

As-written, your intended `dict` `_IdDict`  is really a [type hint](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) ([see comment by **ShadowRanger**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65271748/why-wont-my-python-class-inherit-from-another-class/65271887?noredirect=1#comment115394467_65271872))!

Set the attribute as either a [class variable](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) (probably your intention) or assign the attribute in `__init__()`

---

**Class Variable**
Reference will be created in class declaration and shared by all instances of the class
There is no need to call `super()` to init in this case

```py
class Media_Work():

    _id     = 0
    _IdDict = {}
```

**Attribute**
Reference will be created at class `init` and unique to each instance of the class

```py
class Media_Work():

    def __init__(self):
        self._id     = 0
        self._IdDict = {}
```

Comment: Every time you say "property", you mean "attribute" (more specifically, instance attribute, as opposed to class attribute); [the former has specific meaning in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) separate from attribute.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you're right - I've updated my question with that and a little rework!

Answer (score 1):

It is inheriting, but you haven't defined the `_IdDict` class attribute. `_IdDict: {}` is  [type hint](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), not a definition, and it's a local name in `__init__`, not a class attribute.

Here's an example of how to fix it. You might need to tailor this to fit your needs:

```
class Media_Work:
    _IdDict = {}

class Poem(Media_Work):
    def __init__(self, _id):
        Poem._IdDict.update({_id: self})
```

Example usage:

```
>>> p = Poem(17)
>>> Poem._IdDict
{17: <__main__.Poem object at 0x7f13689a3ba8>}
>>> Media_Work._IdDict
{17: <__main__.Poem object at 0x7f13689a3ba8>}
```

By the way, [don't use `id` as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77552/4518341), since it's a builtin.

Answer (score -2):

[My previous version of this answer was lacking]....  You have two issues there.  The first is that you failed to assign a value to _IdDict so it was not created.  Second, you defined it in the wrong scope.  If you wanted to create a Class attribute you need to refer to it as Media_Work._IdDict from within the __init__ method or you needed to define it outside the method.  Such as:

```
class Media_Work(object):

    _id: int = 0
    _IdDict: {} = {}
    _titleDict: {} = {}

    def __init__(self):
        Media_Work._id = 0
```

Comment: Two of those aren't even class attributes; they're annotations that are never assigned (and by type annotation rules, implicitly annotate the instance attributes, not class attributes). This is not a proper fix at all.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, so true.  I have attempted to improve my bad answer.