# get the value of an attribute in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca5dc.jpg)

```
def PID():
record=[]
for page in range(1,10):
    path=get_link('sugar')
    driver.get(path)
    driver.get(path.format(page))
    id=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
    for i in id:
        results=i.get_attribute('data-id')
        print(results)
```

I would like get the value of `data-id` in this div class as shown in the image, the written code prints the `data-id` along with None Values.

Comment: Please paste HTML in text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest getting all divs with a data-id field. Getting all divs would get some without the attribute.

```
id=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-id]")
```

You can restrict this further by copying the xpath to your parent element in the developer tools inspect element copy xpath and adding it in front of this xpath.

Comment: use find_elements instead of find_element

Answer (score 0):

try using ids as your variable name instead of id, because id() is a fundamental built-in of python (['id' is a bad variable name in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552/id-is-a-bad-variable-name-in-python/28091085))

```
def PID():
    record=[]
    for page in range(1,10):
        path=get_link('sugar')
        driver.get(path)
        driver.get(path.format(page))
        ids=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
        results = [i.get_attribute('data-id') for i in ids]
        print(results)
```

if you want to append results to record then use:

```
def PID():
    record=[]
    for page in range(1,10):
        path=get_link('sugar')
        driver.get(path)
        driver.get(path.format(page))
        ids=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
        results = [i.get_attribute('data-id') for i in ids]
        record.append(results)
```