# Why do I get an empty list?

Tags: python

I want to creat a new list by operating some elements of a price list, but the new list is empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
prices = [2, 50, 70, 30, 555]
new_prices =[]

if int in prices > 20 and int in prices <= 50: 
       new_price.append(int * 0.4)
elif int in prices > 50: 
       new_price.append(int * 0.6)
elif int in prices == 5: 
        new_price.append(int * 0)

print(new_prices)
```

Comment: What do you think `if int in prices > 20 and int in prices <= 50` does? This is a decent attempt at writing some code but illustrates a fundamental misunderstanding of python. I suggest you back up a little bit and learn how to take an action on each item in a list. We do this with a `for` loop.

Comment: And the specific thing you need to learn for your current problem is called a "for loop".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're a little confused on the specific syntax of Python. One thing to note is that while using `int` works here, it should not be done. In Python `int` is a built-in type that your code is overwriting. You should also have a loop to actually iterate over every element of the list. Take this code for example:

```
prices = [2, 50, 70, 30, 555]
new_prices =[]
for price in prices:
    if price > 20 and price <= 50:
        new_prices.append(price * 0.4)
    elif price > 50:
        new_prices.append(price * 0.6)
    elif price == 5:
        new_prices.append(0)
```

Comment: To be technical, ```int``` is a value too, and ```int in prices``` is perfectly valid syntax, it's just not useful.

Comment: @sj95126 you are correct. I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Where are they overwriting `int`?

Comment: @MountQ I suggest you step away from the computer and get a pencil and paper. Write out in words very detailed steps how you would do this by hand. Then you can translate those words into python code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be a confusion between how to iterate through values in python and how if statements work.

If statements simply check whether a given condition is true or not and execute a specific piece of code in the case it is.

So in the first if statement, what you are doing is checking whether the variable `int` is inside the list `prices` is greater than 20... As you can see this sentence doesn't make sense grammatically, because you are trying to check two conditions at the same time without any relation (connectors) between them. On one side you want to know if `int` is in `prices` (which already raises the problem that `int` hasn't been defined) and on the other if 'something' is greater than 20.

My impression of what you wanted to do is something in the lines of: for every value  in `prices` do something if the value is greater than 20. Here you actually would need to go through or iterate for every value within the list `prices`. This can be achieved by using a `for` loop, a while loop with a counter or list comprehensions.
A good example of how to solve this problem with a for loop can be found in @BTables answer.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a typo: first you initiate “new_prices” but you append stuff to “new_price”

Furthermore, I would write the if condition like this

```
for price in prices:
    if price > 20 and price <= 50:
…
```

Answer (score -2):

```
prices = [2, 50, 70, 30, 555]
new_prices =[]
for int in prices:
    if int > 20 and int <= 50: 
           new_prices.append(int * 0.4)
    elif int > 50: 
           new_prices.append(int * 0.6)
    elif int == 5: 
            new_prices.append(int * 0)

print(new_prices)
```

You probably want something like the above. Note your original code had new_price and new_prices.

Output

```
[20.0, 42.0, 12.0, 333.0]
```

Comment: While this works you're overwriting a built-in type. This will *technically* work, but it's very bad practice and should not be done.

Comment: @not_speshal int is not a reserved keyword. 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-Reserved-Keywords-in-Python

Comment: @BTables int() is a function. int is a valid value.

Comment: [In general, using variable names that eclipse a keyword or built-in function in any language is a bad idea, even if it is allowed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552/id-is-a-bad-variable-name-in-python)

Comment: @randomer64 `int` is a valid variable name only in the technical sense here. It's a built-in type and should absolutely not be used in this context.