# How can I make Objects communicate with each other in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

I am making a little project for Neurons on replit.

I made a class called `Neurons`. I set `connections = []`.
I created a function called `connect()` to connect two Neurons via synapses.
If one neuron fires, all of the other Neurons in the `connections` list would receive the signal.

How could I make two different Objects in the same Class communicate with each other, so that the Neurons would know if one of their partners just fired to them?

Here is the code:

```
class Neuron: 
  def __init__(self, type='interneuron'):
    self.type = type
    self.connections = []

  def connect(self, neuron):
    self.connections.append(neuron)

  def receive(self): pass

  def fire(self): pass


n1 = Neuron()
n2 = Neuron('motor')
n1.connect(n2)
```

This link to the replit is here: https://replit.com/@EmmaGao8/Can-I-make-Neurons#main.py.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Since `type` is a built-in function in Python, I would recommend against using `type` as an attribute and variable name. It is better use a name such as `neuron_type`.

Comment: @ShabbirKhan there is no problem with using `type` as an attribute, it won't shadow built-in names.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, yeah, it won't. Using built-in names as attributes just seems like bad style in my opinion. This answer and the comments provide more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28091085/5302861

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go through all of the other Neurons and execute the `receive` function.

For example:

```
def fire(self):
    for other in self.connections:
        other.receive() #and whatever other things you want

def receive(self):
    print("Signal Received!") #or whatever else you want
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are using the `connect()` method of the `Neuron` class to add `n2` in the `connections` list of `n1`, you are creating a link between the instances.

If your print `n1.connetions` and `n2`, you would see that they point to the same object in memory. So you can define the `fire()` method as follows along with a `receive()` method:

```
def receive(self): pass

def fire(self):
    # do something
    for n in self.connections:
        n.receive()
```

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding something, but could you please explain how this adds new information to my (already existing) answer?

Comment: Your answer was posted while I was finishing up mine. Since I had put work into writing my answer, I just decided to keep it.