# Neurons firing simultaneously in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am making a neuron project on Python. In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70285252/how-can-i-make-objects-communicate-with-each-other-in-python), I asked how I could make the neurons fire to each other.

The circuit was successful. I made a new class called "Muscle", that flexes when receiving a signal from a neuron.

But there is a big flaw: When I fire two neurons, say N1 and N2, that are connected to another neuron, N3, then N3 wouldn't sum up the signals it received by **both** N1 and N2. Instead, N3 does them separately, in different times.

How could I overcome that problem?

Comment: Please see [ask] and the [help]. While I encourage you to keep pursuing this, StackOverflow is not meant to be your personal tutoring service. There are guidelines about the nature of questions here, they must be self-contained, for starters. This is not a discussion forum. For questions seeking help debugging code, you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: For a forum that allows for more broad questions and discussion, I suggest checking out an appropriate subreddit, e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/ where you can have an open ended back-and-forth.

Comment: You may want to consider implementing a time window such that if a neuron receives multiple events within the last N seconds, then you sum the events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this answer from https://reddit.com/r/learnpython as juanpa.arrivillaga
recommended:

> ```
> class Neuron:
>  def __init__(self,name,threshold=3):
>    self.name = name
>    self.threshold = threshold
>    self.in_signal = 0
>    self.out_signal = 0
>    self.connect_axon = []
>    self.connect_dendrite = []
>
>  def connect_to_neuron(self, neuron):
>    self.connect_dendrite.append(neuron)
>    neuron.connect_axon.append(self)
>
>  def fire(self, strength):
>    self.out_signal = strength
>    print('neuron',self.name,'fired with strength',self.out_signal)
>
>  def reset(self):
>    self.in_signal = 0
>    self.out_signal = 0
>
>  def update(self):
>    for neuron in self.connect_dendrite:
>      self.in_signal += neuron.out_signal
>
>    if self.in_signal >= self.threshold:
>      self.out_signal =  self.in_signal
>      print('neuron',self.name,'fired with strength',self.out_signal)
>
>
> class Brain:
>  def __init__(self):
>    self.neurons = []
>
>  def add_neuron(self, neuron):
>    self.neurons.append(neuron)
>
>  def update(self):
>    for neuron in self.neurons:
>      neuron.update()
>    for neuron in self.neurons:
>      neuron.reset()
>
> n1 = Neuron('n1')
> n2 = Neuron('n2')
> n3 = Neuron('n3',threshold=5)
>
> n3.connect_to_neuron(n1)
> n3.connect_to_neuron(n2)
>
> tiny_brain = Brain()
> tiny_brain.add_neuron(n1)
> tiny_brain.add_neuron(n2)
> tiny_brain.add_neuron(n3)
>
> n1.fire(4)
> n2.fire(4)
>
> tiny_brain.update()
> ```

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/rd3wts/neuron_project/hnz8hxy/