# Problem with initiating base with child class while working with python-attrs module

Tags: python, mongodb, oop, python-dataclasses, python-attrs

I'm trying to create Model class with [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) module. In my script `CollectionModel` class is inherited in `User` class. So logically all the attributes in the `CollectionModel` should be available in the `User`. But while trying to create a new instance of User from dictionary (it is possible with attrs) it shows that attributes of `CollectionModel` are not present in the `User`

My Script:

```py
from bson import ObjectId
from attrs import asdict, define, field, validators, Factory
import time


@define
class CollectionModel:
    """ Base Class For All Collection Schema"""
    _id : str =   field(converter=str, default=Factory(ObjectId))
    _timestamp : float = field(default=Factory(time.time))

    def get_dict(self):
        return asdict(self)

    def update(self):
        self._timestamp = time.time()

@define
class User(CollectionModel):
    
    username : str = field(factory = str, validator=validators.instance_of(str)) 
    userType : str = field(factory = str, validator=validators.instance_of(str)) 
    password : str = field(factory = str, validator=validators.instance_of(str))



user_object = User()
new_user_object = User(**asdict(user_object))
```

Here, I'm trying to create a new User object from the `user_object`. It shows the following error.

```
TypeError: User.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '_id'
```

I guessed that the parent class is not initiated at first. So I tried to initiate it with the `super()` function and according to attrs documentation it should be done with `__attrs_pre_init__`. From the documentation:

> The sole reason for the existence of `__attrs_pre_init__` is to give
> users the chance to call `super().__init__()`, because some
> subclassing-based APIs require that.

So the modified child class becomes like this.

```py
@define
class User(CollectionModel):
    
    username : str = field(factory = str, validator=validators.instance_of(str)) 
    userType : str = field(factory = str, validator=validators.instance_of(str)) 
    password : str = field(factory = str, validator=validators.instance_of(str))

    def __attrs_pre_init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

But the problem still remains. Am I doing the OOP in the wrong way? Or is it just a bug of **attrs** module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved that issue and there were two problems. The first one, in python, underscore before an attribute name makes it a private attribute. So while creating a new instance from dictionary `_id` is an unexpected key.

The second problem is, I indeed need an `_id` field as I'm working with MongoDB. In MongoDB document `_id` is reserved for using as a primary key.

Now the first problem can be solved by replacing `_id` to `id_` (yes, underscore in the opposite side since `id` is literally a [bad choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552/id-is-a-bad-variable-name-in-python) for a variable name in python).

For the second problem I've searched a lot to make an alias for `id_` field. But it is not simply easy while working with `attrs` module. So I've modified the `get_dict()` method to get a perfect dictionary before throwing my data in MongoDB collection.

Here is the modified `CollectionModel` class and `User` class:

```py
@define
class CollectionModel:
    """ Base Class For All Collection Schema"""
    id_: ObjectId =   field(default=Factory(ObjectId))
    timestamp : float = field(default=Factory(time.time))

    def get_dict(self):
        d = asdict(self)
        d["_id"] = d["id_"]
        del d["id_"]
        return d

    def update(self):
        self.timestamp = time.time()

@define
class User(CollectionModel):

    username : str = field(factory = str, validator=validators.instance_of(str)) 
    userType : str = field(factory = str, validator=validators.instance_of(str)) 
    password : str = field(factory = str, validator=validators.instance_of(str))
```

Now printing an instance:

```py
user_object = User()
print(user_object.get_dict())
```

Output:

```
{'timestamp': 1645131182.421929, 'username': '', 'userType': '', 'password': '', '_id': ObjectId('620eb5ae10f27b87de5be3a9')}
```