# How to correctly call url_for and specify path parameters?

Tags: python, flask

This is the function in views.py:

```
@application.route("/students/<int:id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def students(id):
    return render_template("students.html")
```

I have used this code on my HTML page:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('students', id=student.id) }}">{{ student.id }}</a>
```

But `url_for` is generating this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/students?id=1
```

I want to generate this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/students/1
```

Note that I have another function which was written before that first function:

```
@application.route("/students")
def students():
    return render_template("students.html", students=Student.query.all())
```

I think `url_for` is using this route.

Comment: From the [Flask docs on `url_for`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.url_for): "*Variable arguments that are unknown to the target endpoint are appended to the generated URL as query arguments.*" So, I'm guessing that route with a `<int:id>` is not properly defined or added to your app.

Comment: Do not re use the `id` keyword of python as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have 2 endpoints that have almost the same pattern:

```
/students
/students/<int:id>
```

It then becomes a matter of in what order are those endpoints defined, because the call `url_for('students', id=student.id)` **can correctly match on both**:

- If it matches `/students` *first*, as explained in [`url_for`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) docs: "*Variable arguments that are unknown to the target endpoint are appended to the generated URL as query arguments."*. Since `id=1234` is not a known parameter on this endpoint, it becomes a query parameter `?id=1234`.
- If it matches `/students/<int:id>` *first*, then you get your expected behavior of `/students/1234`

Relying on the order of the endpoints is a brittle and error-prone strategy, so if you think you should just reorder the endpoint definitions, no, that's not the way to go.

What I recommend instead are these options:

1. Rename the functions to help differentiate `url_for` (and readers of your code) that one endpoint is for getting *all* the students, and the other one is for accesing *just one* student *by id*. Then explicitly call the correct one in `url_for`:

   ```py
   @application.route("/students/<int:id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
   def student_by_id(id):
       return {"student": id}

   @application.route("/students")
   def all_students():
       return {"students": "all"}
   ```

   ```html
   <a href="{{ url_for('student_by_id', id=student.id) }}">{{ student.id }}</a>
   ```
2. Similar to option 1, but instead of renaming the functions, pass-in an `endpoint=...` keyword parameter to the `route(...)` decorator to specify different endpoint names. See [the docs for the `route` decorator](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.route) and the section on [URL Route Registrations](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#url-route-registrations) for more details. By default, "*The endpoint name for the route defaults to the name of the view function if the `endpoint` parameter isn’t passed.*". So here, name the endpoint that accepts an `id` as `"student_by_id"` and explicitly use that in `url_for`.

   ```
   @application.route(
       "/students/<int:id>", 
       methods=["GET", "POST"], 
       endpoint="student_by_id",  # <---------
   )
   def students(id):
       return {"student": id}

   @application.route("/students")
   def students():
       return {"students": "all"}
   ```

   ```html
   <a href="{{ url_for('student_by_id', id=student.id) }}">{{ student.id }}</a>
   ```
3. Combine both into 1 endpoint. Then the endpoint function should first check if `id` was specified. If it was, then handle processing for just 1 student. Else, handle processing for all students. The `url_for` call doesn't need to be changed.

   ```
   @application.route("/students")
   @application.route("/students/<int:id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
   def students(id=None):
       if id:
           return {"student": id}
       else:
           return {"students": "all"}
   ```

   ```html
   <a href="{{ url_for('students', id=student.id) }}">{{ student.id }}</a>
   ```

Pick one which works best for you.

As a side note, [as mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72111773/how-to-correctly-call-url-for-and-specify-path-parameters#comment127415545_72111773), I also recommend ***not*** using `id` as a parameter or variable name, because you might accidentally [shadow the built-in `id()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77552/2745495). It might be actually be more readable to change it to `student_id`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have understood that I didn`t knew how url_for working.