# Can 'id' be used as variable name in python?

Tags: python

Whenever I use `id` as my variable name, my IDE shows the term in different colour from other variables. Is this expected or is it some feature of IDE (I'm using vs code) or shouldn't i use `id` as a variable?

I haven't faced any issues while running code. Only the colour change makes me curious.

Example Image from my IDE:
[image: Example Image]

Comment: This is because `id` is an builtin function

Comment: It is a bad practice few keywords a reserve for python builtin methods, when you can use it then it can create a mess.

Comment: technically its possible but it's very bad practice because id is builtin.

Comment: in a class this is fine, it doesn't shadow anything

Comment: Not a dupe.  This is fine; the answers are (IMHO) wrong.  Having an attribute on a class shadow a builtin is *not* the same as shadowing a builtin in a function, and *not* the same as shadowing in global/module scope.  `id` only shadows *outside* the methods.  I highly doubt you shold be calling `id` in the definition of a class anyhow.  (NB I'm assuming this is a dataclass).

Comment: However since this is dupe-hammered I can't post an answer, so answering in the comments...

Comment: @2e0byo logically correct...Idk why i've tried python IDE, VScode, Jupyter notebook, Spider...They are highliting `id` inside the `class`

Comment: Even shadowing `id` in a function might well be alright: in some logic `id` can only ever mean something *other* than `id()` (e.g. a db lookup for ephemeral objects).  Whether such a (small) function would pass code review is a matter for local styles, but there are arguments both ways.  Lots of code out there still uses `match` for `re.Match()` objects, even though that has now become syntax.  Python worked to make that work (by ignoring `match` outside pattern matches).  But all/most of the IDES will highlight these `match`s, despite them *not* being syntax in these instances.

Comment: @Bhargav until `id` is defined it's the `id()` builtin.  The ide probably just uses a glorified regex anyhow, but `Foo.id` is *never* going to be `id` unless you bind it explicitly.  Yeah, it does stop you calling `id()` at eval time in the outer class scope, but that's a pretty big code smell already.  If the OP isn't using something like `@dataclass` there's a bigger problem with this class, since `id` clearly belongs on the instance.

Comment: Wow what a  keen observation!..Never thought of that!

Comment: The point about `match` btw was just that Python is pretty averse to breaking existing code, and it's extremely unlikely to forbid shadowing at any point in the future.  You shoudn't do it willy-nilly, but there are definitely cases (like class attributes) where it can make sense.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer @2e0byo..it may be helpful to others ..a lot of information here!!

Comment: I couldn't find a canonical dupe for this, so I've created one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74274877/when-is-it-acceptable-to-shadow-a-builtin/74274878#74274878).  The answer is a community wiki.

Comment: ... and the canonical I made has since been closed as opinion based.  Oh well.

Comment: @ilyasbbu what is that, it looks real nice.

Comment: @se7en What do you mean?

Comment: @ilyasbbu sorry, I mean what Theme is that. I want to download it

Comment: @se7en it is [noctis-high-contrast](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Kamen.noctis-high-contrast)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Shorter Answer:

You *can* use `id` as a variable name, but should not. That being said, in the example you gave, you are using id as a class' attribute (not a variable) which is fine to do.

#### Longer Answers:

As noted by other answers, `id` is a [builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), so naming a variable `id` is not ideal as it obfuscates the underlying function. There is a question with more detail about *why* this can cause problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552/id-is-a-bad-variable-name-in-python/28091085#28091085).

However, the example in the screenshot you provided is *not* using `id` as a variable, but as a class' attribute (you can read more about classes and their attributes in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) on the subject). This is fine as there is no builtin attribute named `id` (credit to "juanpa.arrivillaga" for first noting this in a comment on a different answer). The fact that it is highlighted differently is likely an error in your IDE/text editor's syntax parsing.

Answer (score 1):

In Python3, `id` is Built-in Functions.

refs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id