# When is it acceptable to shadow a builtin?

Tags: python

We are often told not to shadow builtins like `id`, `int`, `list` and so on.  Is it ever acceptable to break this rule?

Answer (score 5):

In general, you should not shadow builtins for several reasons:

- doing so prevents you from using the builtin later by calling its common name
- other people reading your code will be confused, as they expect `list` to be the builtin `list`, and so on
- IDEs will (usually) compound this by highlighting your shadowed variables as though they were builtins.

However there are some exceptions.

### In class attributes

Using a builtin name in a class attribute doesn't shadow anything at all at runtime, although it might at evaluation.  This pattern is quite common:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, foo_id: int) -> None:
        self.id = foo_id
```

`Foo().id` was *unbound* until we bound it in the constructor.  No shadowing is going on here.  The use of `id` to mean "identity" is sufficiently common that it is probably better than any alternative (like `obj_id` or `identity`), and nobody is going to expect `Foo().id` to be the builtin `id`.

If you use dataclasses, this might involve shadowing:

```py
@dataclass
class Foo:
    # id refers to the builtin `id`
    id: int = 0 # assigning a default for the example
    # id referes to `Foo.id`, which has the typehint int

foo = Foo(id="id of foo")
# foo.id refers to the *instance* id, which is actually a string.
```

In this example we *do* shadow `id`, briefly.  We couldn't use it at evaluation time.  But you probably shoudn't be getting the id of an object when defining (not constructing) a class anyhow.  Because of the way dataclasses work, we end up with a separate `id` on the instance `foo` (which as is demonstrated here, doesn't even have to be the right type!).  There are three namespaces at play: the enclosing namespace, in which `id` means what it normally does, the namespace of the unininstantised class `Foo`, in which `id` is 0, and the namespace of the object `foo`, in which `id` is a string.  We have shadowed in the second of these, but we don't do anything in that namespace later anyhow.

### In small functions, when clarity demands

It *might* be acceptable to shadow the a builtin in a small function which can never conceivably use the shadowed object, *if* doing so increases clarity.  Both of these are probably fine:

```py
def get_object_from_db(id: int) -> CustomObj:
    ...

def find_enclosing_dir(filename: str) -> Pathlib.Path:
    f = _find_file(filename)
    dir = f.parent
    some_logic_to_validate(dir)
    return dir

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, id: int) -> None:
        self.id = id
```

The first example shadows `id` in a function in which the only 'id' we care about is the database id for the data we're retrieving to build our `CustomObj`.  Nevertheless, using `obj_id` here might well be clearer.  The second example shadows `dir` and uses it for a directory.  `dir` and similar introspection tools are very unlikely to be used in this code; again `parent_dir` *might* be clearer, but shadowing here is a stylistic choice.  In the third example we shadow `id` in the constructor for `Foo`.  Again, we cannot now use `id`, but our code is arguably cleaner.

### After thinking twice

In general, avoiding shadowing is a good thing.  Inside a small function or method it might make sense to shadow a builtin for clarity.  This should only be done when it increases clarity, and the work of refactoring to avoid the shadowing if something changes down the line is tiny.  At the very least the function should fit comfortably on one screen.  Class attributes can 'shadow' with impunity (as they don't shadow at all), but only a few names open themselves up to being used like this.  `id` and maybe `dir` make sense, but `Foo.list` or `Foo.str` is probably *less* clear than a descriptive name.

Comment: I’m probably in the minority but I find this view *way* too dogmatic. In practice it’s absolutely fine to liberally shadow builtins (and other stuff) inside functions (including for parameter names). In most cases there’s no confusion, and the alternative is to use convoluted names that *decrease* readability. The biggest impediment to doing this are annoying, overzealous linter warnings that don’t actually understand code quality and just mindlessly apply overly broad rules.