# Why does SQLAlchemy recommend using built-in `id` as column name?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using reserved keywords or built-in functions as variable/attribute names is commonly seen as [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552/id-is-a-bad-variable-name-in-python).
However, the SQLALchemy [tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/quickstart.html) is full of exampled with attributes named `id`.

Straight from the tutorial

```
>>> class User(Base):
...     __tablename__ = "user_account"
...
...     id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
...     name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
...     fullname: Mapped[Optional[str]]
...
...     addresses: Mapped[List["Address"]] = relationship(
...         back_populates="user", cascade="all, delete-orphan"
...     )
...
...     def __repr__(self) -> str:
...         return f"User(id={self.id!r}, name={self.name!r}, fullname={self.fullname!r})"
```

Why is it not recommended to use `id_` instead, as recommended at least for keywords in [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, `id` is not a keyword; if it was one, you would get a syntax error (try replacing `id` there with e.g. `pass`). It is a global identifier for a built-in function. And while it is a bad practice to clobber over the default identifiers defined by Python, note that `id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)` inside a class definition defines a static attribute of that class, not a global variable. The global function `id` is not the same as the static attribute `User.id` (or `self.id`, as it is used later) — there is no conflict there.

```
class Foo:
    id = 42

print(Foo.id)
# => 42
print(id)
# => <built-in function id>
```

However, as you correctly note:

```
id = "YOU SHOULDN'T DO THIS"
print(id)
# => YOU SHOULDN'T DO THIS
# (and not <built-in function id>)
```

Secondly, as to why `id` is used: SQLAlchemy maps classes to SQL tables with the snakecased class name, and attributes to SQL columns with the as-is attribute name (unless you specifically say `id_: mapped_column('id', primary_key=True)`), so `id` and `id_` would be different columns in SQL.

`id` (as opposed to `id_`) is the conventional name of the primary key column in SQL (if there is a single-column primary key). Some people would name the column `user_id`, but many dislike having `user_id` in table called `users`, since it should be obvious what `users.id`, and so `users.user_id` is redundant; the form `user_id` is generally reserved for foreign keys. The SQLAlchemy examples merely follow this SQL convention.